# How to apply free shipping method for specific country?

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping

I wants to make shpping free in **country A** and in **country B** I want to make free shipping above 1000 USD.

I had tried with shopping cart rules, but I am not getting better solution for this conditions.

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're best of using the native Magento Tablerates extension.

Go the `System > Configuration > Shipping methods > Tablerates`, set `Condition` to `Price vs. Destination` and next switch to the website you want to apply it to.

Hit the CSV download button to get a CSV you can modify and take a look at the screenshot below on how to set shipping over a subtotal of $1000 to free for a specific country.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to System->Configuration->Shipping Methods->Free Shipping.
Fill in the field `Minimum Order Amount` with the value `1000`.
From `Ship to Applicable Countries` select `Specific countries`.
And in the field `Ship to Specific Countries` select `Country A` and  `Country B`.
Save and that's it.

Comment: Thank you Marius, But I had tried this way, not getting success. If I am apply this rule, then for Country A also getting free shipping as well as another shipping method.

Comment: This is actually how it should work. By enabling Free shipping, does not mean the other shipping methods should not be visible.

Comment: Actualy, If I am enable freeshipping for "country A" without minimum order and I have place order with "country A" shipping country then In shipping method only show free shipping method. So I want this kind of situation for both conditions.